# C# MVVM Calling ViewModel method from Code Behind using NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I can't seem to get a method in my ViewModel to run successfully from my XAML code behind when using NotifyIcon.  The method executes correctly, as tested with debugging mode using breakpoints, but nothing happens in the View.

The method in question is RefreshData, and it can be called from either a button in the View (works as expected), or from right clicking the NotifyIcon and selecting Refresh Data (does nothing).  I'll post relevant code below.  Any help would be appreciated!

MainWindow constructor in CodeBehind

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            MM = new MMViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();                
            DataContext = MM;

            _notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            _notifyIcon.DoubleClick += (s, args) => ShowMainWindow(this);
            _notifyIcon.Icon = Migration_Monitor_v2.Properties.Resources.mmc;
            _notifyIcon.Visible = true;

            Closing += MainWindow_Closing;

            CreateContextMenu();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error("App failed with exception: ", e);
        }
    }

    private void CreateContextMenu()
    {
        _notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        _notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Refresh Data").Click += (s,e) => MM.RefreshData();
        _notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Exit").Click += (s, e) => ExitApplication(this);
    }
```

RefreshData method in ViewModel (works when executed from the Refresh button in the View)

```
    public void RefreshData()
    {
        InfoPanelVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
        InfoSummaryVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        Task.Run(() => LoadData());
        n = DateTime.Now;
        ProgressBarText = "Click a project to show progress";
        ProgressBarValue = 0;
        lastRefresh.Reset();
        lastRefresh.Start();
    }
```

LoadData method (and associated methods) called from RefreshData

```
    public async void LoadData()
    {
        IsLoading = Visibility.Visible;
        await GetWebApiInfo();
        MonitorData downloadInfo = main;
        try { AssignDataToControls(downloadInfo); }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e); }
        finally { IsLoading = Visibility.Hidden; }
    }

    public void AssignDataToControls(MonitorData mon)
    {
        MainPanel.Clear();
        MonitorText.Clear();
        mon.MainPanel.ToList().ForEach(x => MainPanel.Add(x));
        mon.MonitorText.ToList().ForEach(x => MonitorText.Add(x));
        Information = mon.Information;
        ProgressData = mon.progList;
    }

    public async Task GetWebApiInfo()
    {
        var url = "::::WEB API ADDRESS::::";
        string responseFromServer;
        using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient())
        using (var dataStream = await _client.GetStreamAsync(url))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.Unicode))
            responseFromServer = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        main = deserializer.Deserialize<MonitorData>(responseFromServer);
    }
```

RefreshCommand from ViewModel Commands.cs file

```
internal class RefreshCommand : ICommand 
{
    public RefreshCommand(MMViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private MMViewModel _viewModel;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _viewModel.CanRefresh;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.RefreshData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing pops out at me.  You claim "The method executes correctly", but it's not clear what method(s) you're talking about.  If you were to, for example, place breakpoints at the start of each method, then click on the notification icon, how far down the call stack do you actually manage to go?  You can add an Action to the breakpoints so it just prints out the name of the method that was just executed in the debug console, which is convenient.

Comment: Next, I'd check the assumption that the view model is what you think it is.  Put a breakpoint in the LoadData method.  Trigger it from the taskbar and, when it is hit, assign an Object ID to `this` (search for the term if you don't know how object ids work). Next, trigger it from the window.  When the breakpoint is hit, check `this` to see if it has an object id.  If not, your data context is being changed somehow.

Comment: Seems like a job for CompositeCommand to me. That is a "shell" command that lets various VMs subscribe to it for handling CanExecute / Execute.

Comment: @Will With a breakpoint on the opening curly brace for LoadData I get this: MM.ViewModel.MMViewModel.LoadData() called from MM.ViewModel.MMViewModel.RefreshData.AnonymousMethod__68_0.  I have this set as the action: $FUNCTION called from $CALLER.  The Refresh button in the application works, running Refresh Data from right-clicking the NotifyIcon in the Windows System Tray does not work, but it returns the same output as I just listed above.

Comment: I'd trace it all the way down the callstack to make sure (no assumptions at this point), then go do the object id thing,

Comment: @Will Sorry if this is noob-ish, but I'm still a bit new to using debugging.  I found an article referring how to set the Object ID, but it doesn't seem to work.  Compiler complains that "error CS0103: The name '$1' does not exist in the current context."  I have 'this' set to {$1}.  Any help or documentation on how to get this to work?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/04/make-object-id/

Comment: There is a difference, but I'm not really sure what to make of it.  Thoughts?  http://imgur.com/a/5BlpW  Edit: Looks like they're calling from different instances of MMViewModel...though I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue.  The problem was that my ViewModel was being constructed three separate times, so it was unclear to the command which instance was being referenced.

To fix this, I removed references to the ViewModel in my XAML Window definition space.  There were 2 references I thought I needed for the ViewModel as a local namespace (i.e. x:local.VM="MM.MyViewModel").  After removing those, the ViewModel is only being constructed once and all code is running as intended.  Thanks to @Will for his help getting to the bottom of this!